# Why I cannot read from files in java

Tags: java

I have problems with reading external files. When I tried to read `in.nextDouble` or `in.nextInt` or so on it throws `InputMismatchException`. In only one case I can read file - when I use `in.next()`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Echo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("numbers.odt"));
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            double next = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("number " + i + " = " + next);
            sum += next;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.

Comment: Even in.next() gives me very strange output like :

Comment: @MiroslavIvanov output like what...?

Comment: An odt file is probably not plain text (open / libre office uses a zipped xml, if I remember correctly). Your code expects numbers as in a text file, but the file has some compressed data. That's also what the exception tells you: what you try to read does not match what's there.

Comment: Please include (some representation of) input, expected and observed behaviour. Provide a [MCVE], if possible.

Answer (score 2):

This problem about your file format. Code works for .txt format. I created "numbers.odt" file. It didn't work. I created "numbers.txt" file. It worked. I changed "numbers.txt" file's name by "numbers.odt". It worked.

"numbers.txt" contain:
1 2 3 4 5

You should learn how can you read the odt file with Java.